# .NET Core - EF - trying to match/replace strings with digits, causes System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-core, entity

**I have to match records in SQL around a zip code with a min/max range**

the challenge is that the **data qualities are bad, some zipcodes are not numbers only**

so I try to match "good zip codes" **either by discarding bad ones or even keeping only digits**

- I dont know how to use Regex.Replace(..., @"[^\d]", "") instead of Regex.Match(..., @"\d") to fit in the query bellow
- I get an error with the code bellow at runtime

I tried

- Regex.IsMatch
- SqlFunctions.IsNumeric

they all cause errors at runtime, here is the code :

```
var data = context.Leads.AsQueryable();
data = data.Include(p => p.Company).Include(p => p.Contact);
data = data.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p.Company.ZipCode, @"\d"));
data = data.Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Company.ZipCode) >= range.Min);
data = data.Where(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Company.ZipCode) <= range.Max);
```

here is the error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Lead>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Company>, 
        inner: l => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "CompanyId"), 
        outerKeySelector: c => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(c, "Id"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Lead, Company>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Where(l => !(Regex.IsMatch(
        input: l.Inner.ZipCode, 
        pattern: "\d")))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I am not sure how to solve this. I really don't see how AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync() could help here

what do I do wrong ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you use a queryable list, EF Core 5 is always trying to translate query to SQL, so you have to use code that SQL Server could understand. If you want to use C# function you will have to download data to server using `ToList()` or `ToArray()` first, and after this you can use any c# functions using downloaded data.

You can try something like this:

```
var data = context.Leads
.Include(p => p.Company)
.Include(p => p.Contact)
.Where(p => 
    p.Company.Zipcode.All(char.IsDigit)
&& (Convert.ToInt32(p.Company.ZipCode) >= range.Min)  //or >=1
&&  ( Convert.ToInt32(p.Company.ZipCode) <= range.Max) ) // or <=99999
.ToArray();
```

Comment: so there is no way to do a match or a replace on sql side ? with entity ?

Comment: apparently IsDigit cannot be used with All, I get a parameter error, maybe I can write my own function for that

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything imaginable

all sorts of linq/ef trickeries, I even tried to define a DBFunction that was never found

once I had a running stored procedure written dirrectly in SQL, I ended up with a list, not with an IQueryable, so I was back to #1

finaly, I just created a new field in my table :

**ZipCodeNum**

which holds a filtered , converted version of the zipcode string